# Connection Reset when attempting to list all files from a Sharefolder

Tags: java, samba, smb, ntlm-authentication

I am trying to recursively check for a specific file in my company sharefolder using `SmbFile` and `NtlmPasswordAuthentication`.

As I am not very knowledgeable in Java I followed examples found in the internet but I keep getting the following error whenever I try to do a `root.listFiles()` :

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: foldername/xx.xx.xx.xxx
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I do have access rights to the sharefolder so my initial thought is that something is missing from my code but instead an authentication or proxy error. I am using the url in the following format: `smb://foldername/something/somethingelse/anothersomething/`


My code:

```
    public static Boolean checkDiretory(String location, String docName){
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", Consts.username, Consts.password);
            SmbFile root = new SmbFile(location, auth);
            List<SmbFile> files = Arrays.asList(root.listFiles());
            for(SmbFile file : files){
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    result = checkDiretory(file.getPath(), docName);
                    if(result)
                        return result;
                }
                else{
                    if(file.exists() && file.getName().contains(docName)){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is your target server? It may not support SMB1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Eliad Cohen suggested, you might have to change to [SMBJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) due to incompatibility of SMBv2 in jcifs.

I've found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098675/vfs2-and-sambasmb-version-2) which may help you to solve this matter.

Keep in mind that the host is just your path!

Happy coding!